# Is there a good reason not make all iPhone / iPad graphics with only retina dimensions?

Tags: ios, graphics, retina-display

I understand the need to upgrade your non-retina graphics to retina graphics if the app was originally designed with non-retina graphics.  If you aren't converting old apps, is there a reason to make 2 different size graphics?  Since retina graphics can scale down but non retina can't scale up, why not just make all graphics with retina dimensions?  This seems to save a lot of time (making each graphic 2 sizes / naming each graphic appropriately, etc.) although it may take up a trivial amount of space.  Is there something I'm overlooking if I don't make all my iPad and iPhone apps based off retina dimensions only?

Comment: You could also look into automating the creation of 1x images as part of your build process, so you don't have to maintain two copies of each asset.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can we just provide @2x images?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767079/can-we-just-provide-2x-images)

Comment: I included only @2X images for iPhone5 specific update for my app and found out that iPhone5 do not display the image.  I had to include the non 2X images and that fixed the issue.  iPhone5 simulator display the images just fine but not the actual device so keep this in mind.

Answer (score 2):

The main reason is simply performance, if the system has to scale all images down it could impact performance.

Also I'm not sure if the non-retina systems will load an image if only the @2x image is available.  That would require some testing in the simulator.

Comment: The main reason is the downsampling problem as I describe in my answer below. Downsampling algorithms are quite optimized so there is little risk of slowing your app. For example, UIImageView uses a scaling algorithm and it can be placed in thousands of rows without impacting performance.

Comment: Also, iOS defaults to loading the retina image and scaling if a non-retina is unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with only including Retina graphics is that, as you say, the device would have to scale down all of your assets before displaying them. This might well be a negligible impact on your app's performance. The bigger problem is that downscaled graphics look crappy, *especially* since they're going to be displayed on lower-resolution screens. All of your scaled images are going to look mediocre at best. Maybe you could spend a lot of time developing images that iOS will scale well, but at that point, why not just generate separate image files? It doesn't take much effort to generate 1x assets, and your users will notice the difference.

Comment: A 100px x 100px is obviously much sharper than a 50px x 50px image.  If the 100 x 100 is scaled to a 50 x 50 it will loose much of its sharpness.  It seems the original 50 x 50 vs the scaled image will have trivial differences.. no?  Yes the scaled image will look "crappy and mediocre" but the non-retina graphics are already "crappy and mediocre".

Comment: There are definitely nontrivial differences between images that have been downscaled by an algorithm (even a good algorithm) and those that have been downscaled by a human designer. Using the former to save a small amount of time *will* be noticed by your users. Sure, non-Retina displays are kinda crappy, but you'd be treating your non-Retina users with contempt if you ignore them during the design phase.

Answer (score 0):

As Kendall answered, one reason is peformance, but the other is visual quality.

A image designed to retina, when automatically downscaled can become unsharp:
For an image to be pixel sharp it has to be designed for non retina:
This includes not placing lines on fractional coordinates, they would be between to pixels, leading to visualy lower quality.

Comment: Do you know what algorithm iOS uses to downsample images? And why doesn't it intelligently use a more appropriate algorithm to get sharper pictures? (I may post this as a separate question)

Answer (score 0):

When **creating** images for your app, it's **much** better to lower the resolution prior to exporting it. Images will render better than if you create a .png file, and then resize it.

Imagine a 8px*8px square being scaled down to 4px*4px.

If you reduce your png file, a 2px*2px square will correspond to a single pixel. The resulting color won't be perfect. If you reduce your image prior to exporting it, it will render better.

So, if you create those images yourself, it's better to reduce them manually, and before exporting them.

If you use "already flat" images, wether you or the OS operate this "bad" downscale,you'll have the same result. But if you give the system the non-retina images, your app will run more smoothly as you spare the OS the time to create the low res images.

Answer (score 0):

Performance is one factor. Also, for small icons, you want pixel perfect images for the screen size. The scaling algorithm on iOS is generically smooth but you want it sharper when you get into small icons.

Comment: This is the only answer that explains why iOS doesnt do the downsampling well. You would normally expect that Apple can do an image processing algorithm correctly. However, It is because it uses the same algorithm as it uses with up sampling. And also, this problem is only visible for small icons. Large pictures are generally scaled correctly, as the scaling algorithm is more appropriate for pictures.